# Existence of measure factorization

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space, $(X,\mathcal B)$ a measurable space and $m$ a probability measure on $\Omega\times X$ such that its projection on $\Omega $ is equal to $\mathbb P$.

When $m$ has a factorization with respect to $\mathbb P$?

Comment: What is $(X, \mathcal{B})$ for? I think $m$ is defined over $(\Omega, \mathcal{P})$...

Comment: Can you double-check your notation, and explain what you mean by "factorization"?

Comment: I guess paul wants to determine whether there exists a measure $\mu$ such that $m=\mathcal P\otimes \mu$.